# How to add inline components inside a default Bootstrap 3 form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to add an "inline" control inside a `form-group` class in TB3 but I am not able to do it. This is what I've tried without success meaning it does not work as I want:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form id="new_question" method="POST" class="form-vertical" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="field_type_id">Select a Question Type</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="field_type_id" name="field_type_id">
            <option value="">Select One</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="field_name">Question Text</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="field_name" id="field_name" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Option 1</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value=""> Checkbox
          </label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the snippet/example above I would expect:

- Keep the first and second element as it's: the label on the top then the HTML element
- Make an inline version of the third element: first have the option, then the HTML, then the checkbox which mean everything in one line.

The idea is to have something like:

```
Label1 Input1 Checkbox1
Label2 Input2 Checkbox2
```

Does any knows how to achieve this? It has to be done only in a certain lines so the rest of the form behaves as the [form basic example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you might want to use columns from the [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/):

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
        <label>Some label</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> Check me out
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The above example creates 3 equal-width columns using predefined grid class `col-sm-2`

Answer (score -3):

Create a 
Give it a class of Flex
Set the width

```
<div class='flex'>
<div> item1</div>
<div> item2</div>
<div> item3</div>
</div>

<div class='flex'>
<div> item4</div>
<div> item5</div>
<div> item6</div>
</div>

.flex {
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Codokk101/pen/goQNOW